# unexpected "{" error while trying to use for loop with an if statement

Tags: r

I am trying to get the mean of the outer values of every possible triplet in a row with 15 values in total. I tried this and got the error.

```
for (i in 1:12){
  if (!is.na(data[1,i] & data[1,i+1] & data[1,i+2])){
    a[i] <- apply(data[1,i],data[1,i+2],1,mean,na.rm=T)
  }
}
```

I have looked everywhere but couldn't find a solution. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please format your code so that it's easier to read and read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: now it shows a "dim(x) must have a positive length" error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be you can also try:

```
 outer.triplet.mean1 <- function(x,...) {
 indx <- 1:3+ rep(0:(length(x)-3),each=3)
 m1 <- matrix(x[indx], ncol=3, byrow=T)
 rowMeans(m1,...)
  }

 outer.triplet.mean1(1:10)
 #[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

 outer.triplet.mean1(c(1:5,NA, 5, NA, 10, NA, 1:5))
 # [1]  2  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2  3  4

 outer.triplet.mean1(c(1:5,NA, 5, NA, 10, NA, 1:5),na.rm=T)
 # [1]  2.0  3.0  4.0  4.5  5.0  5.0  7.5 10.0  5.5  1.5  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

with >1 row

```
 apply(rbind(1:10,1:10),1, outer.triplet.mean1)
```

Comment: the vandals tend to do that a lot! I have the same problem! Haha

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does what you want to do while dealing with NA. It takes a single row of data.

```
outer.triplet.mean = function(x){
  a = integer(length(x)-2)
  for (i in 1:length(x)-2){
    a[i] = ifelse(!any(is.na(c(x[i], x[i+1], x[i+2]))), mean(c(x[i], x[i+2])), NA)}
  return(a)
}

> outer.triplet.mean(1:10)
  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> outer.triplet.mean(c(1:5, NA, 5, NA, 10, NA, 1:5))
  2  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2  3  4
```

If you want to run it over all the rows.

```
sapply(data, outer.triplet.mean)
```

Comment: what should we insert in place of x exactly?

Comment: x -> a row of values you want to calculate the triplet outer mean for, ie data[1,].